# Access 2007 Split form VBA: acNewRec on open prevents tabbing through form - acts like the first field is not 'selected'

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, tabstop

I hope someone can help me out, or at least help figure out a workaround.

I'm using Access 2007's split form feature, and have the code below run on the Form_Open event, as well as after two button_click events.  The code works fine when run after the button_click events, but when it runs on the form_open event, it causes problems.

If form is opened and user enters text in the first field, he/she cannot use Tab or mouse to select the next form field.  The user is stuck on the first form field until pressing Esc to cancel the data entry.  In order to successfully enter data in the first form field when the form is opened, a user must first select another form field, then re-select the first form field then enter text in first form field. After this nonsense, the user CAN select next form field with Tab or mouse.  This must be performed once every time the form is launched.  The same VBA code on the button_click events works fine.

Noteworthy: When the form is first opened, NONE of the form fields in the datasheet section of the form appear 'Selected'.  When a user begins to enter data in the first form field, the 'new record' marker (*) moves to the second row as it should, but the first row does not show the data being input.  This behavior is odd.

After performing the clear field, click another field, click back to first field workaround described above, the datasheet shows properly selected fields and Data as it is input.

Any ideas?  Is this a bug?  Is there an easy workaround, such as performing the field-select workaround via VBA at form open?

Any help is MUCH appreciated.

Code:

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "([Contractor].[CheckOutStamp] Is Null)"
DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
```

Link to mdb:
https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B-jx09cwIQDsYWM2MzMzMDQtYjUzNi00N2E5LWFjYTktNzFiYWYzMDZiYWU1&hl=en&authkey=CPPmoMEF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thoughts:

Try moving it from OnOpen to OnLoad. The events in OnOpen can happen before the data is actually loaded, where as OnLoad happens after that is already done.

Also, you might want to just set the form's Filter property to `[Contractor].[CheckOutStamp] Is Null` and set the FilterOn to Yes, and set the form to DataEntry, which means it defaults to a new record upon open, and doesn't load any of the older records. Once it's open, you can change the form's edit/add mode to whatever you like.

Comment: Just moving the code to the OnLoad event fixed the particular problem I was having.  
The DataEntry property worked as advertised, but was not useful for me, as I need old records displayed on load.
I went ahead and set the Filter property and FilterOn as you suggested, to filter if a user does not enable VBA, but I left the VBA filter code as well.

Comment: Just keep in mind that if you edit the recordsource, the filter properties will get reset.